# Method returns the number of times that three or more consecutive keys appear

Tags: java

For the question that currently has me stumped, I'm supposed to write a static method named countTriples that will take any int array as a parameter, and an integer key, and return the number of times that three or more consecutive keys appear. A sequence of more than three keys still counts as one triple.

pseudocode example: countTriples([1 3 3 3 0 3 3 1 3 3 3 8], 3) => 2

pseudocode example: countTriples([1 7 7 7 0 7 7 7 7 1 7 7 7 7 7 8], 7) => 3

pseudocode example: countTriples([1 14 14 4 1 14], 14) => 0

Here's what I have so far, it works for some cases, but not for ones such as: {1,2,1,1,1,5,6,7,8,1,1,1,1}

```
import java.util.*;
public class Sample {
    public static int countTriples(int[] data, int key) {
        int count = 0;
        int c= 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
            if (data[i] == key) {
                c++;
                if (c >= 3) {
                    count++;
                    c = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,2,1,1,1,5,6,7,8,1,1,1,1};
        countTriples(arr, 1);//currently returns 1, 2 expected
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: In the Array: `[1 7 7 7 0 7 7 7 7 1 7 7 7 7 7 8]`, wouldn't `7 7 7 7` actually count as **2** and ` 7 7 7 7 7` count as **3**? This would then provide a total of **6**, not **3**. Or am I wrong about this?

Comment: Wondering the same thing ^

Comment: A sequence of more than three keys still counts as one triple, but yeah, that's what I had trouble with the first time since it was overlapping

Comment: What does key represent? The number you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, it represents the "clumps" of numbers you're looking for

Comment: A question very similar to this was asked (and someone actually answered) about four of five hours ago. Do a search for **Consecutive Three in Array**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create an initial loop and loop through all values until we find one that matches the key. When we do we create another loop to start at the next index until we find one that doesn't match, or until we hit the end (this is important). Once we hit a non-key value we check if the offset in the current for-loop is 3 or greater than the initial for-loop. If so, we increase count and offset the initial loop by the amount we looped in the second loop to ensure no duplicates.

```java
    public static int countTriples(int[] data, int key) {
        int count = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            int valueAtIndex = data[index];

            if (valueAtIndex != key) {
                continue;
            }
            for (int offset = index + 1; offset < data.length; offset++) {
                int valueAtOffset = data[offset];

                if (valueAtOffset != valueAtIndex || offset == data.length - 1) {
                    int indexOffset = offset - index;

                    if (indexOffset >= 3) {
                        index += indexOffset - 1;
                        count++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```